# How to use two sound sources while using recordMyDesktop?

Tags: sound, recordmydesktop

I'm using ***recordMyDesktop*** and here is my problem: I need to record the sound emitted by my desktop and put some comments on it at the same time.

For now, I have no problem commenting what's on screen, my microphone records my voice correctly, but there is any way I can record the sound made by the software as well?

Comment: i'm afraid that is not possible. you can record with the internal card and then, record your voice apart and mix the two with a video editor.

Comment: And I recommned OpenShot for VideoEditor.... VERY easy to use,

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/410737/record-desktop-and-microphone-audio-with-avconv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that!

***The*** proper way to do this is to **use JACK sound server,** which is fully supported by recordMyDesktop. There is a nice GUI app for controlling it (though it's name is terrifying) - `qjackctl`.

You will want to use the *Connections* window of qjackctl, it will allow you to learn which audio input is which, and will enable you to direct **both** your system input & microphone input to your system speakers.

Once your JACK server is running, launch recordMyDesktop. If you use `gtk-recordMyDesktop` you will be provided with a list of all JACK channels in the settings window (make sure to choose two with the Ctrl key in order get stereo sound!). If you run recordMyDesktop from command-line, you will need to experiment with command-line parameters, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Instead of routing all audio you want to record to system speakers, you might also experiment with different JACK connection schemes. Use it as you like. And note that there are many JACK connections tutorials for begginers, if case you found JACK difficult.

PS. You may find this article helpful: http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6491/2

Comment: Please expand this answer with more precise steps. I think this is precisely what I am looking for.