# Record from two ports of the same source simultaneously with PulseAudio

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

After a lot of searching and finding nothing which seems to be of any help, I came here to ask help from someone smarter than me.

I need to record 2 audio feeds simultaneously. The one is from the Line In at the back of the computer, and the other from the microphone at the front. The reason for this is one will be the output of a speaker's voice, and the second from the translation service. However, these two devices uses the same "Source" according to the `pactl list` command. Here is the output:

```
 Source #2
 State: IDLE
 Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
 Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
 Driver: module-alsa-card.c
 Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
 Channel Map: front-left,front-right
 Owner Module: 5
 Mute: no
 Volume: 0:  56% 1:  56%
         0: -15,30 dB 1: -15,30 dB
         balance 0,00
 Base Volume:   9%
              -63,00 dB
 Monitor of Sink: n/a
 Latency: 70035 usec, configured 371519 usec
 Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
 Properties:
  alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
  device.api = "alsa"
  device.class = "sound"
  alsa.class = "generic"
  alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
  alsa.name = "ALC662 rev1 Analog"
  alsa.id = "ALC662 rev1 Analog"
  alsa.subdevice = "0"
  alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
  alsa.device = "0"
  alsa.card = "0"
  alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
  alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xfe420000 irq 47"
  alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
  device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
  device.bus = "pci"
  device.vendor.id = "8086"
  device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
  device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
  device.form_factor = "internal"
  device.string = "front:0"
  device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
  device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
  device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
  device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
  device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
  device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
  alsa.mixer_name = "Intel CougarPoint HDMI"
  alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0662,103c1497,00100101 HDA:80862805,80861497,00100000"
  module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
  device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
 Ports:
  analog-input-microphone: Microphone (priority: 8700, available)
  analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, available)
 Active Port: analog-input-microphone
 Formats:
        pcm
```

In the recording software (called Galicaster) one creates profiles with the location of the source you need to capture, like such:

```
[track3]
amplification = 1
name = Line In
vumeter = True
location = alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
file = sound.mp3
device = pulse
path = /home/capture/Repository/attach
flavor = presenter
active = True
```

Basically, I need to know how to specify the port that needs to be used for each track, for example:

track3 needs to use the `analog-input-microphone` port of Source2, and track4 (the second audio track) needs to use the `analog-input-linein`

Does anyone have any idea how I can specify this? I have tried using a simple append like `location = alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.analog-input-microphone`, or `location = alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo:analog-input-microphone`, but nothing is working. The recording software boots up with error.

Is there a way to this, and if yes, how?

Comment: This may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/410737/record-desktop-and-microphone-audio-with-avconv