# What screen recorder records my desktop audio?

Tags: games, screen, recordmydesktop

Hi I am looking for a screen recorder that allows me to record my voice,screen, and desktop audio. RecordMyDesktop doesn't work. The desktop audio doesn't show up.Kazam doesn't either. It lags the video. I need help! I am new to Linux so a simple explanation would help a lot.

Comment: You may setup a pulse `loopback` then use any screen recorder that support pulse backend, or used a recorder that support multiple audio sources like `avconv` look for xvan's answer . Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/410737/record-desktop-and-microphone-audio-with-avconv/ . As you can make more advanced setup using pulse using virtual devices as here  https://askubuntu.com/questions/421014/share-an-audio-playback-stream-through-a-live-audio-video-conversation-like-sk/421056#421056 , it will eat some CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleScreenRecorder, install it using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

if you want to record 32-bit OpenGL applications on a 64-bit system:

```
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386
```

[image]

For more info : http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/

Comment: Will it record game audio?

Comment: @ThePerfectoGamer: it works with mic....... not pretty sure about system sound...