# how to get background sound work in recordmydesktop

Tags: recordmydesktop

I cannot get any sound Recordmydesktop

by sound I mean the background song or video volumes which are ongoing in my desktop

I have a video of what I am doing to get sound but eventually not getting it its over [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7ucgL5fpzY)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/63363/how-to-use-two-sound-sources-while-using-recordmydesktop?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record desktop and microphone audio with Avconv](http://askubuntu.com/questions/410737/record-desktop-and-microphone-audio-with-avconv) It should cover pulseaudio settings you trying (set as default the Monitor: Analog Stereo Audio).

Comment: @Sneetsher i cannot get any option for input devices. i have uploaded a screenshot of it to my question

Comment: @agharehanabbas, `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` then run `pavucontrol` from terminal

Comment: @Sneetsher pavucontrol is already installed in my pc

Comment: i have added a video on youtube about what i am doing to get my background sound its is here http://youtu.be/Jia-6inZOWk

Comment: @agharehanabbas, I put things you need here as answer, what you are missing **in bold**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install Pulse Audio Control

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
  ```
- Open terminal & run: `pavucontrol`
- This is to record **Playback Only** (no microphone): Number are same on screenshot.

  1. Goto Input Devices tab
  2. Show: **All input devices**
  3. Use Green Button to the right to Select "**Monitor**: Audio Analog Stereo"

  *There are different channel names but You can run some player and see which has signal.*

  When Gnome Volume Control is opened, It overrides it back to Microphone. I have noticed that in the late releases 13.04, 13.10, 14.04. It cannot be changed back using Gnome Volume Control. (Avoid using it on recording)

[image: Pulse Audio Control : Input Devices]

Comment: i still can't get the volume output see this video to see what am i actually doing http://youtu.be/6ZpKqZgAcXQ

Comment: @agharehanabbas, missing step 3, your default should be set to top input. When you played sound did you see its volume meter moving. (lower channel was silent)

Comment: i have done the same thing again but i cant get it see this video now http://youtu.be/bf_ogYHntI4

Comment: yes the lower channel was silent but i could still hear the sound through woofers

Comment: @agharehanabbas, that's correct. Restart recorder

Comment: so what might be the reason of my failure to record the audio

Comment: thats done i can get sound now thanks @sneetsher

Answer (score 1):

I have a one liner script to capture screen. It can capture both mike and desktop voice.

It's not very good, but I hope it serves the purpose.

```
 avconv -f   pulse -i default -f x11grab -r 15 -s $(xdpyinfo  | grep dimensions | awk -F ' ' ' { print $2 } ' ) -i :0.0+0,0 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264  $(date +"%m%d%Y_%H%M%S_$HOSTNAME")_screencast.mp4
```

Comment: is this a plugin for recordmydesktop

Comment: @agharehanabbas
no, it's terminal command to record your screen. To stop it press `ctrl-c`

Comment: i want to record the desktop with audio which is already running in background

Comment: `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key[x11grab @ 0x6e6940] Cannot open display :0.0+0,0, error 1. :0.0+0,0: Input/output error` :/