# how to record long hours of gameplay without audio error

Tags: sound

i'm trying to record long hours of game play that i could watch on my way to school but i'm having an issue with simple screen recorder where because of how long the recordings are it seems to remove audio from the video. furthermore, i can't skip to later parts of the video because every time i click a place further into the video, nothing happens. i'm using a Lenovo y50 running Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

`RecordMyDesktop` first records everything as raw data and writes it onto the disk (`/tmp`). It then renders the video after it was completely captured. This shouldn't have the problem, which could be caused by running out of ram, using too much CPU power, etc. `RecordMyDesktop` barely uses any ram or CPU power while recording.

Comment: i tried using record my desktop but unfortunately when i play the output video the whole thing is sped through really fast and the audio of the video is from the mic input, when what i want is to record the game audio

Comment: You can set FPS and audio source when you click on "Advanced".

Comment: i didnt know about changing the fps settings. ill take a look at it when i get home. but i did try to change the audio source but the options were shaded out and unable to make changes to them

Comment: i changed the fps settings. that seems to have fixed the visual issue. however, im not sure how to transmit audio from the speakers and not from the mic while using this program

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63363/how-to-use-two-sound-sources-while-using-recordmydesktop

Comment: i looked into that. when i installed qjackctl and looked thru the "audio" section of the connections settings, but no readable clients/output ports are recognized, and as a result the whitespace underneath the readable clients is blank

Comment: can someone pls answer my question so i can get this thing working?

Comment: can someone on this forum pls be useful for once?