# Stereo sound capture BUT one different device per chanel: MIC / Audio Output in Ubuntu

Tags: sound, microphone

I am using recordmydesktop to record my videoconferences, and I know it is able to record several audio channels simultaneously (whatever the heck "channels" means) because I type "man recordmydesktop" and I can read:

> Sound Options:
>
> --channels N(number>0)
>                     A positive number denoting desired sound channels in recording.

I want to have the mic captured in the left channel, and the audio that the other person sends to me and I can hear through the speakers, in the right channel.

Right now I am recording only through the mic, and then the sound of the speakers is also recorded but it goes throuth the mic, hence it is very crappy but, most important if I try to use headphones to avoid waking up the whole neighborhood with my late night videoconference with someone at the other side of the globe, it only records my voice and not what the other person says.

If I could do that, I would be able to use headphones with mic. The left channel would have my voice, and the right channel the voice of the other person.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

I am sure the answer has [a lot to do with this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/115452/198166) but I don't manage to work out the details.

Comment: basically channels are like left, right, side left, side right, rear left, rear right, center and sub ... I haven't looked into the recordmydesktop app but .. you would want to set it up for it to record the mic input on channel 1 or what ever is left in the apps manual .. and set the input on channel 2 or what ever right would be to "what you hear" or the computers sound output. This is just basic .. I would have to do research on how to accomplish this because as I say I don't really know the app

Comment: I looked a bit more into it and also installed `gtk-recordmydesktop` for a graphical interface ... I don't see how to select inputs on it tho :( .. I do see you would need to set it to record 2 channels so you could set one channel to the mic input and one to the window you are recording but not sure that would even work .. there is a spot to select ports for the channels but its blank on mine .. not sure I have it set up right .. my audio has never really been right on my Ubuntu box :D lol

Comment: @JohnOrion The answer has something to do with a program called Jack Sound Server but I am unable to work out the details. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63363/how-to-use-two-sound-sources-while-using-recordmydesktop

Comment: lol yeah started the QjackCtl and started the server .. now I have a bunch of ports but .. none labeled very user friendly .. but .. I guess you can play with the settings and try to figure out which ones you need to have connected and recorded ... at least you have them .. now its just a bunch of experimenting

Comment: I would try to help but like I say .. my sound isn't 100% on my linux box and it's a server so its not really important enough for me to bother to fix it so you are going to have to see if you can go through the documentation of both apps and see if you can make heads or tails of it .. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Bigger question that needs to be worked out first is - how can i create a working JACK sound system with all required audio recording sources? Answer to that is beyond scope of a short question on here

Assuming working JACK audio, audio recording settings in recordmydesktop:

[image: recordmydesktop sound settings]

will create the recording connections in JACK:

[image: qjackctl connections]

This is not a stereo mix. recording two sound sources in mono makes it easier to edit in post-production.

Recording all sources in stereo is possible by adding more connections in qjackctl, or using a mixer in JACK

Comment: I'm traveling now, so I cannot test this. But it is sort of important for me, so rest assured that I will test it and accept the answer in a couple of weeks. For the moment, thanks for your answer.